# MySQL Store procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL using sqlworkbench, how can I create a procedure for a table to get the input value (only the first 100 rows) from the text file and store it in the database?

For example: in the text the values like (12, abc, heg, 258) like 100 rows.

Please help me with this.

I have Tried

```
DELIMITER $$ 

drop procedure if exists `proctable` $$
create definer =`root`@`localhost` procedure `proctable`(in C:\Documents and Settings\Sridevi\tablevalue.txt varchar(200)) 
begin
load data local infile C:\Documents and Settings\Sridevi\tablevalue.txt 
into table test.testtbl
fields terminated by  '|' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
end $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: on small doubt. how to find my database. don't be angry. i used the command show databases; and select one on that but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop procedure if exists `proctable`;
DELIMITER $$ 

create definer =`root`@`localhost` procedure `proctable`(/*remove that parameter*/) 
begin
/*the filename and the path to it have to be in quotes*/
load data local infile 'C:\Documents and Settings\Sridevi\tablevalue.txt' 
into table test.testtbl
fields terminated by  '|' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
(your_column_names_here, column2, column3, column4)
end $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Your parameter name when creating the procedure is not the path to the file, it has to be a variable name, which you can reference in the procedure itself. Here's an example, though I'm not sure if the `load data local infile` command works with a variable. You'll have to try this yourself.

```
drop procedure if exists `proctable`;
DELIMITER $$ 

create definer =`root`@`localhost` procedure `proctable`(IN my_variable varchar(255)) 
begin
/*the filename and the path to it have to be in quotes*/
load data local infile my_variable
into table test.testtbl
fields terminated by  '|' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
(your_column_names_here, column2, column3, column4)
end $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

and you would then execute the function with

```
CALL proctable('C:\Documents and Settings\Sridevi\tablevalue.txt');
```

Comment: on small doubt. how to find my database. don't be angry. i used the command show databases; and select one on that but its not working.

Comment: How did you "select" it? Why is it not working? Error messages? Have you issued the command `use your_database;`?

Comment: error message is displaying like 'no database selected'. i am using from the client machine and the table is stored in the client.

Comment: using MySQL Workbench

Comment: Hm, unfortunately I'm not familiar with workbench, but I'm sure you just have to doubleclick your database somewhere. Maybe you can ask over at superuser.com

Comment: hey the database is connected now but its saying. load data is not allowed in store procedure.

Comment: Is that so? Okay, didn't know that. Well, then don't use it in a stored procedure. You can issue the command without using one.

Comment: @bennyraj A quick search on google reveals, that there are workarounds if you really want to use it in a SP...